# google search xml api sorting

Tags: xml, api, search, google-custom-search

I am using google search xml api
I need to search on my site by one of my PageMap attributes, so I am using custom search as it in https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search
(as it is in the example I have &sort=date-sdate:d and all pages has this attribute in right format)

q=*+more:p:{dataobjectname}:{attribute} and getting 18 results
But if I want to sort results by attribute as default (hard) (:h) I am gettting no results.
Using sort on :s or :w works fine, but I am getting my results unsorted

So why (:h) is not working?

Comment: First of all tag your question correctly, name the languages, technologies and tools you're usingbecause the question is useless without that info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that attribute isn't working, but I suggest you start by trying to get it working here:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOUR_CC_PROJECT/apiui/api/customsearch/method/search.cse.list
(subbing YOUR_CC_PROJECT)

This console is quite useful for testing the API before moving to code, but note that some people complain that they can only do a few per day before they get cut off.